# Reverse geocoding API java

Tags: reverse-geocoding

I am trying to reverse geocode latitude ans longitude coordinates to a zip code in java. Is there any simple API to do this? If you know of any good tutorials I should be able to figure it out.  I have tried Opencage but cannot get it to work on JRE 1.8.0. A point in the right direction would help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google reverse geocoding. Not sure if its free

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: Thats javascript I'm using java, but I'll see if I can get it working. Seems like I need to also use JSON to send and read results. Thank you.

Comment: May be, this might help you
https://rapidapi.com/blog/google-maps-api-java/

Comment: This is a good tutorial, but this method of converting latitude and longitude to a zip code is not free. Does anyone possibly know of a free API that will do this. I am working on getting Opencage to work but am having some trouble understanding how to implement a library someone else designed that I downloaded from github.